# Verifying transformed string was actually changed (according to mapping table)

Tags: algorithm, verification

I have a mapping table, `M`:

[image: mapping table]

And using this, I've performed a find & replace on string `S` which gives me  the transformed string `S'`:

`S: {"z" "y" "g" "k"} -> S':{"z" "y" "h" "k"}`

Now I wish to verify if my mapping transformation was actually applied to `S'`. The psudo-code I came up for doing so is as follows:

```
I.  Call function searchCol(x, “h”); // returns true if “h” can be found in column x in M. 

II. If searchCol(x, “h”); returns true {
    // assume mapping transformation was not applied to S'
    // S'' after transforming S': {“z”, “y”, “i”, “j”}
}

III.If searchCol(x, “h”); returns false {
    // assume mapping transformation was already applied to S'
    // do nothing
}

IV. // log and continue …
```

However, as you can see, for the case above the algorithm doesn't work. Does anyone know a better way of going about this?

Cheers for your help.

**Note**: As my codebase is in Java, if you do provide any code examples, I'd prefer it if you posted them in the same language :)

Comment: Before anyone says this, no this is not a homework. I'm just trying to build this on top of my tool to automate the checking of changes it made.

Answer (score 1):

Can you instead keep track of transformations? There are some cases where it's impossible to determine if a transformation took place, imagine this mapping table:

```
x -> y
y -> x
```

Now given the String `yxyxyxyx`, was it already transformed? And how many times?

But even if your mapping table is free of circles, the only thing you can say is:

```
If the string contains a char that is on the left side and not on the right side,
then it was not yet transformed.
```

But if the above condition is not fulfilled, then you can not be sure of anything.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point I was thinking about when I made the question but keeping track didn't occur to me. So how should this tracking be done? Would I have to add some metadata to a log perhaps which states the exact transformation made? So log would show: `x->y` & `y->x`. Then to check, reverse map `y` for first example, and reverse map `x` for second example. Or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are the one doing the transformations you could for example wrap every string in an object with a transformation-counter. Whenever you transform, you increase it.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, and yes I'm doing the whole thing.